# Globalize.with_locale in after_commit callback does not change anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, globalize3, rails-i18n

I'm having troubles with Globalize3 gem when updating cached attribute in after_commit callback.

```
#In My Model
after_commit :write_localized_caches
private
def write_localized_caches
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    Globalize.with_locale(locale) do
      self.write_attribute(:name, 'some localized string here')
    end
  end
end
```

It launches after_commit callbach and the value for the attribute is fine. But after all my model's name is still empty!

Maybe I'm misusing `with_locale` or does anyone faced the same problem?

**UPDATE 1.**
I definitely want to use after_commit callback to perform complex queries on saved objects. 
Printing out self.name inside the callback returns just what i want: 'correct_string'. But id does not hit the  Database.
Ended up with writing a new translation creation. Seems like Globalize uses callback in its basement:

```
def write_localized_caches
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  Globalize.with_locale(locale) do
    self.translations.create!(name: 'some localized string here', locale: locale)
  end
end
end
```

This works, but still does not feel right to me!

Answer (score 0):

After commit is called after the database has completed saving the record.

if you insert print statements such as

```
def write_localized_caches
  puts self.name # the name that you're seeing in the database

  # Globalize Block

  puts self.name # The name that was set above most likely
end
```

Also keep in mind that returning false or nil from a callback will abort the callback chain and reverse the database transaction. Though, after_commit is called after the transaction is complete, so it matters less here.

you probably want before_save.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. I definitely want it to happen in after_commit callback because of complex queries. See the update above.